# javascript function returns as "null" instead of null value

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function:

```
  getToken: function () {
        return localStorage.jwtToken;
    },

  this.getToken()!=null //true,
```

so basically this function returns "null" instead of null, how can I make the function return the null value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Comment: How did you *set* the value? You've confirmed that `this.getToken()` returns `"null"`?

Answer (score 2):

You probably did:

```
 localStorage.jwtToken = null;
```

to set it to `null`, but as `localStorage` can only contain string properties, it got stringified to `"null"`. Instead of setting it to `null` set it to `undefined`, or just delete the key:

```
 localStorage.jwtToken = undefined;
 localStorage.removeItem("jwtToken");
```

Answer (score 0):

If instead of `"null"` you want to return `null`, return this expression

```
getToken: function () {
        let token = localStorage.jwtToken;
        return (token === "null") ? null : token;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

`this.getToken()!=null` returns **true** because you are only checking the value.

If you want to check the **value** and **type** you need to check with `!==`.

`this.getToken() !== null`